# Angular 2 Deployment Change Base Tag During Build

Tags: angular, deployment, angular2-routing

my current Angular 2 app, before I do `ng build prod`, I need to go into my index.html file and change the base tag from  `<base href="/">` to  `<base href="/myExampleApp/">`

But as you know, I need to change my local version back to "/" because by changing the local version of the base tag, I will break my local served app.

Is there an elegant way where I can do `ng build prod baseTag='xyz'`?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
# Sets base tag href to /myUrl/ in your index.html
ng build --base-href /myUrl/
ng build --bh /myUrl/
```

https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular-cli